Wrong BitLocker Status Retrieval for Encrypted USB Drive Using WMI in C#
I'm trying to retrieve the BitLocker status of a USB drive using WMI in C#. I have written the following code to determine the protection status, conversion status, and encryption method of the drive. The code works well for a non-BitLocker protected USB drive but returns wrong results for a BitLocker-protected USB drive. Here is my code:

private static void CheckBitLockerStatus(string driveLetter){
try {
    
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption");
    scope.Connect();

    var query = new ObjectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume WHERE DriveLetter = '{driveLetter}'");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    var volumes = searcher.Get();

    if (volumes.Count == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine($"No BitLocker information found for drive {driveLetter}.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (ManagementObject volume in volumes) {
        
        ManagementBaseObject protectionStatusParams = volume.InvokeMethod("GetProtectionStatus", null, null);
        uint protectionStatus = (uint)protectionStatusParams["ProtectionStatus"];

        ManagementBaseObject conversionStatusParams = volume.InvokeMethod("GetConversionStatus", null, null);
        uint conversionStatus = (uint)conversionStatusParams["ConversionStatus"];

        ManagementBaseObject encryptionMethodParams = volume.InvokeMethod("GetEncryptionMethod", null, null);
        uint encryptionMethod = (uint)encryptionMethodParams["EncryptionMethod"];

        string protectionStatusDescription;
        if (protectionStatus == 0)
            protectionStatusDescription = "Protection is Off";
        else if (protectionStatus == 1)
            protectionStatusDescription = "Protection is On";
        else if (protectionStatus == 2)
            protectionStatusDescription = "Protection is Unknown";
        else
            protectionStatusDescription = "Unknown Protection Status";

        string conversionStatusDescription;
        if (conversionStatus == 0)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Fully Decrypted";
        else if (conversionStatus == 1)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Fully Encrypted";
        else if (conversionStatus == 2)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Encryption In Progress";
        else if (conversionStatus == 3)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Decryption In Progress";
        else if (conversionStatus == 4)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Encryption Paused";
        else if (conversionStatus == 5)
            conversionStatusDescription = "Decryption Paused";
        else
            conversionStatusDescription = "Unknown Conversion Status"; 

        string encryptionMethodDescription;
        if (encryptionMethod == 0)
            encryptionMethodDescription = "None";
        else if (encryptionMethod == 1)
            encryptionMethodDescription = "AES 128-bit with Diffuser";
        else if (encryptionMethod == 2)
            encryptionMethodDescription = "AES 256-bit with Diffuser";
        else if (encryptionMethod == 3)
            encryptionMethodDescription = "AES 128-bit";
        else if (encryptionMethod == 4)
            encryptionMethodDescription = "AES 256-bit";
        else
            encryptionMethodDescription = "Unknown Encryption Method";

        Console.WriteLine($"Drive: {driveLetter}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Protection Status: {protectionStatusDescription}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Conversion Status: {conversionStatusDescription}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Encryption Method: {encryptionMethodDescription}");

        ManagementBaseObject keyProtectorsParams = volume.InvokeMethod("GetKeyProtectors", null, null);
        string[] keyProtectorIDs = (string[])keyProtectorsParams["VolumeKeyProtectorID"];

        if (keyProtectorIDs != null && keyProtectorIDs.Length > 0) {
            Console.WriteLine($"BitLocker is configured on drive {driveLetter} with key protectors.");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine($"No key protectors found on drive {driveLetter}. BitLocker might not be configured.");
        }

        if (protectionStatus == 0 && conversionStatus != 1) {
            Console.WriteLine($"BitLocker is configured but not actively protecting the drive {driveLetter}.");
        }
        else if (protectionStatus == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine($"BitLocker is actively protecting the drive {driveLetter}.");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine($"BitLocker status for drive {driveLetter} could not be determined.");
        }
    }
}
catch (ManagementException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("A WMI error occurred: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("You do not have the required permissions to perform this operation: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error occurred: " + ex.Message);
} }


When I run this code for a BitLocker-protected but decrypted USB drive, I get the following output:
Drive: F:

Protection Status: Protection is Off
Conversion Status: Encryption In Progress
Encryption Method: Unknown Encryption Method

My Questions:

Why does the GetProtectionStatus method return "Protection is Off" while GetConversionStatus returns "Encryption In Progress" even though nothing is in progress?
Why is the GetEncryptionMethod returning "Unknown Encryption Method"?
How can I correctly determine the BitLocker status of the USB drive, especially when it has been decrypted?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these inconsistencies would be greatly appreciated.
